# How to Print all source code in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, printing

I was wondering how to print all of my source code within my solution/project for a code review in visual studio.
I have created a C# application with a database and was wondering if there was anyway to print the C# source code in one go without printing each one individually.

I have tried using the VS code Print extension, however, it will not export the document to a pdf or document to print without paying for it and it also leaves a huge watermark on it too.

Thanks in advance.